# Unable to install lwc local server VS code

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

from yesterday I'm trying to install LWC local development server using
`'sfdx plugins:install @Salesforce/lwc-dev-server'` 
but i'm getting an error a weird error like this.

> Polling for new version(s) to become available on npm... done
> HTTPError: Response code 403 (Forbidden)
> Code: ERR_NON_2XX_3XX_RESPONSE>

I came across this link *https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-dev-server-feedback/issues/160* mentioning some another person experiencing similar error(I'm using MacOS).
Any thoughts/suggestion will be really appreciated
(I've already tried to update CLI, and reinstall the CLI as well, restart VS code, setting project again, downgrade Node to v17.9.1 but nothing seems to work)

currently I have -- node v17.9.0, -- npm v8.11.0

Thanks!!

Comment: I’ve already reached out to the concerned Salesforce Product team internally and I will update this thread as I have a meaningful update. Thank you

Comment: This is now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved.  The signature file had been deleted and is now restored.

Comment: Note for others seeing this in one of the review queues. Shane appears to be a _very authoritative source_.

Comment: Resolved now, able to install, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update @Shane! @Derek F , He is part of Salesforce  Product team